# Click dones't work fine with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the following HTML/jQuery script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    $(function(){
        $('#add').click(function(){
            count++;
            $('#container').append(count + '° posto: '+ '<input type="text" id="item_' + count + '" name="items[]" type="text" /><input type="submit" name="del" id="del" value="Elimina" /><br />');
            return false;
        });
        $('#del').click(function(){
            alert('prova');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <span>1° posto:</span><input type="text" id="item_1" name="items[]" maxlength=<?php echo $psw_length[1]; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="del" id="del" value="Elimina" /><br />
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Aggiungi" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Avanti >" />
</form>
```

If I click the first "Elimina" button, the alert appears but if I click the second, the third, the fourth, etc. doesn't happen anything.

Can someone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: Or you should use a class instead as I have shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your elements are dynamically added, you need to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler.

***Note:*** You are adding same `id` of `del` which is incorrect. An `id` should be unique for each element.

In order to work around it, you can use a ***class*** instead:

```
class="del"
```

And then use this code with `on` handler for dynamic elements:

```
$('form').on('click', '.del', function(){
      alert('prova');
      return false;
});
```

Comment: The first button is not in `#container`. Attach the event to `form`!

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for noticing that. Updated

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:
 `id` must be **unique**!!!. Change from `id` selector to `name` selector

You need to use a delegate event like `on` or `delegate` (`live` is deprecated).

```
$('#add').click(function(){
            count++;
            $('#container').append(count + '° posto: ' +
               '<input type="text" id="item_' + count + 
               '" name="items[]" type="text" /> ' +
               '<input type="submit" name="del" value="Elimina" /><br />');
               // ===> Not duplicating the del id!!! 
            return false;
        });
$('form').on('click', 'input[name="del"]', function(){ // <== delegate event.
            alert('prova');
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery **on** event for dynamicly created controls.
**Do not use live it is obsolete!**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    $(function(){
        $('#add').on('click', function(){
            count++;
            $('#container').append(count + '° posto: '+ '<input type="text" id="item_' + count + '" name="items[]" type="text" /><input type="submit" name="del" id="del" value="Elimina" /><br />');
            return false;
        });
        $('#del').on('click', function(){
            alert('prova');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <span>1° posto:</span><input type="text" id="item_1" name="items[]" maxlength=<?php echo $psw_length[1]; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="del" id="del" value="Elimina" /><br />
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Aggiungi" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Avanti >" />
</form>**strong text**
```

Comment: Your code doesn't generate a delegate event! you are missing the selector parameter...